# Find all surfaces that can be obtained from an octagon by identifying edges in pairs.

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces

Find all surfaces that can be obtained from an octagon by identifying edges in pairs.

I think there are many many surfaces. Can anyone give some hints for the question?Thanks.

Comment: Is the question "what surfaces can be paved (without overlapping) by a regular octagon?"

Comment: Given the "algebraic topology" tag, I assume that this refers to topological surfaces obtained by identifying the sides of an octagon pairwise.

Comment: What does it mean to "obtain" a surface from an octagon?

Comment: Sorry I correct my question

Comment: @MichaelSeifert : indeed, I didn't paid enough attention to the tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that there are a very large number of edge symbols that you can get 
by pairwise identifying the edges of an octagon.  However, many of them yield homeomorphic surfaces.  Here are a few facts that might help you in your thinking:

- The classification theorem for surfaces states that any compact 2-manifold is homeomorphic to either a sphere, a connected sum of $n$ tori, or a connected sum of $n$ projective planes.
- A torus is obtained from an edge symbol with four letters.  A projective plane is obtained from an edge symbol with two letters.
- The connected sum of two surfaces with given edge symbols can be obtained from a polygon whose edge symbol is just the concatenation of the original two edge symbols.

Based on these three facts, you should be able to make a very short list of the possible surfaces that can be obtained.  I'm purposefully omitting the exact number of surfaces that I think there are, so that I don't give the whole game away.  I will say that if I'm right, it's less than 10.

(Background:  I'm following the discussion of edge symbols and polygon identification in Massey's *A Basic Course in Algebraic Topology*.  It's also possible to understand this all in terms of quotients of free groups on a finite number of generators, but I'm a little rustier on how that's done, so I'll leave that discussion to someone else.)

Comment: So, all connected compact surfaces are sphere, torus, real projective plane $\mathbb{P}^2$, $\mathbb{P}^2$ # $\mathbb{P}^2$ and $\mathbb{P}^2$ # $\mathbb{P}^2$ # $\mathbb{P}^2$ # $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: I think some of them contains some perforations. For instance, we have also cylinder, that is, sphere with two perforations. We can also get Mobius strip

Comment: True, I was assuming that we obtained a surface without boundary.  Allowing the surface to have a boundary would extend the list;  I'm not sure how many components the boundary could end up with.  (At least two, but I'm not sure that you could get more than that.)